# Article page navigation using swiping left or right - Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm developing article reading app.At this moment articles can be read using verticle scrolling.Now I have a new requirement where the article's page navigations using swiping left or right.It's like [**Kindle App**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazon.kindle&hl=en).Please see [**this gif too**](https://i.imgur.com/3bkehHr.gifv).Do you know any component or like that with Ionic 3 and angular?

Right now the code is as shown below.

**.html**

```
 <div class="main-content">
   <div padding class="textContent"  [innerHTML]="articleData?.definition?.meaning?.text"> </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Ionic 2's Gestures](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#gestures) to handle user iterations, like swipe, and then navigate trough pages (using NavController).

Or you can use [Ionic's slider component](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/) to slide contents within a page (but you can't navigate through pages).

Comment: Can't we have an Angular component for handling it like a read a book as shown on GIF image above?

Comment: You can use Ionic's slide component: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/

Comment: Yes, I need to navigate within the page.But article may have more than one page.Hope we can use this no?

Comment: You can't use slider o navigate. Slider is used to present multiple content within the same page. To navigate, you have to implement navigation using swipe gesture.

Comment: Which component should I use to implement this? Thanks. https://i.imgur.com/3bkehHr.gifv